# Why do markers, patterns, and unicode characters display incorrectly in a svg data uri in google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, svg, data-uri

I am using google chrome version 24.0.1312.57 on Mac OS X 10.6.8.

In Safari 5.1.7 the svg image looks like this:

[image: svg_safari]

In Chrome it looks like this:

[image]

Notice the markers are gone from the paths and the path that has a pattern now has a fill of black and the unicode character has an A behind it. This only happens if the image is a data uri in the address bar in google chrome.  If I open the svg image up as a file in chrome it displays correctly.

I've tried taking the line endings away and putting it in base64, but it doesn't seem to fix anything.

Is this a bug with chrome or am I missing something?

Here's the source svg:

```
<svg width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svg_elem">
<title id="doctitle">URI Test</title>
<defs id="thedefs">
<pattern id="ptrn" overflow="visible" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
         x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"
         viewBox="0 0 10 10" >
    <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="-5" y1="-5" x2="15" y2="15"/>
</pattern>

<marker id="mtriangle" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="0" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3" orient="auto">
  <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z" fill="#FFF" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1"/>
</marker>

<marker id="mcircle" viewBox="-2 -2 12 12" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth" markerWidth="4" markerHeight="3" orient="auto">
  <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="5" fill="#FFF" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1"/>
</marker>  

</defs>

<g> 

<path 
fill="#F00"
stroke="#000000" 
stroke-width="3" 
marker-start="url(#mtriangle)"
marker-mid="url(#mcircle)"
d="M10,10l0,60l60,0z"/>      

<path 
fill="url(#ptrn)" 
stroke="#000" 
stroke-width="3" 
marker-start="url(#mtriangle)"
marker-mid="url(#mcircle)"
d="M110,110l0,70l70,0z"/>      

<text 
fill="#000" 
x='100'
y='100'
font-size="14pt" 
font-family="serif" 
text-anchor="middle"
space="preserve">N 34° 45' 30" E 300 ft</text>

</g>
</svg>
```

Here's the data uri.

```
data:image/svg+xml;base64,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
```

Comment: Interesting. I also see the bug in chrome (windows), but it's good in firefox.

Comment: It worked fine in firefox for me too on mac.

Comment: Try adding an <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> first in the document (or otherwise ensure the text encoding is correct).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about markers and patterns, but as for the character set, Chrome must be using a different default encoding for data:URIs. If you add `charset=UTF-8;` in the beginning, e.g.:

```
data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8;base64,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
```

...it should work properly!

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxegG/).

**EDIT** Upon further inspection (re: markers and patterns), it seems like this is a bug in Chrome. It looks like Chrome incorrectly interprets (*completely ignores?*) `url(#hash)` attribute values in SVG data:URIs when embedded as `<object>` (and possibly in other cases?).

Here's [another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sHAa4/) with extensive testing of this issue.

Everything works correctly for me in Safari 6.0.2, Firefox 18.0.2 (Mac), Firefox 10.0.1 (Win), Opera 12.12 (Mac), and IE 9. `<object>` ([as well as](http://jsfiddle.net/kAHkM/) `<embed>` and `<iframe>`) embeds are not displaying correctly in Chrome 24.0.1312.57 (Mac/Win) or 26.0.1405.0 canary (Mac), whereas `<img>` embeds are working fine. Pasting either the URI-encoded or base64-encoded data:URIs into the address bar is also not working.

Comment: Thanks for answer about the unicode characters and the testing with the markers and patterns.  I wonder if the bug has been reported yet.

Comment: I haven't had time to search though the chrome bugs yet, but if you feel like it, go ahead ;). Feel free to use my test fiddles in a bug report if you do submit one.