# Chrome fails to display createObjectURL encoded image pattern in a svg data uri

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, svg, uri

I am using Google Chrome 46.0.2490.80

The problem is that the browser fails to  to display createObjectURL encoded image pattern in a svg data uri.

Here is the jsbin: https://jsbin.com/petulu/edit?html,output

```
<body>
    Choose an image to fill<input id="f-input" type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">
    <br/>The svg image:
    <br/>
    <div id='isvg'>
        <svg version="1.1" width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <defs>
                <pattern id="pat1" patternUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1" viewBox="0 0 1 1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <image id="patImg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="" width="1" height="1" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
                </pattern>
                <pattern id="pat2" overflow="visible" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10">
                    <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.5" x1="-5" y1="-5" x2="15" y2="15" />
                </pattern>
            </defs>
            <g>
                <path fill="url(#pat1)" stroke="#000000" d="M10,10l0,60l60,0z" />
                <path fill="url(#pat2)" stroke="#000000" d="M110,110l0,70l70,0z" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>The svg image after base64 encode:
    <br/>
    <div>
        <img id="svgb64" />
    </div>
    <script>
        var loadFile = function (event) {
            var URLObj = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var patImg = document.getElementById('patImg');
            var imgObjURL = URLObj.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
            patImg.setAttribute('xlink:href', imgObjURL);

            var isvg = document.getElementById('isvg');
            var html = isvg.innerHTML;
            console.log(html);
            var svgb64 = document.getElementById('svgb64');
            svgb64.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + btoa(html);
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

In the Firefox browser (version 42.0), after chose an image, I correctly got the following:

[image]

In the Google Chrome, after chose the same image, I got the following:

[image]

The image pattern (cat) was lost in Google Chrome after the SVG is base64 encoded!

I suppose the Android webView has the same problem. How can I overcome this? I mean, how can I enable the Chrome to display the image pattern correctly in a svg data uri.

Here is the image I used for the test:

[image]

The relevant problem is:

[Why do markers, patterns, and unicode characters display incorrectly in a svg data uri in google chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14741810/why-do-markers-patterns-and-unicode-characters-display-incorrectly-in-a-svg-da)

Comment: You should use patImg.setAttributeNS rather than patImg.setAttribute to set the xlink:href attribute. Not sure this will fix your problem though.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks. I tried patImg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href', imgObjURL); But it did not solve the problem. I suspect this is a bug of the Chrome browser, because Firefox does not have the same problem.